# How to insert a new row with a varying number of parameters

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have read lots of posts related to this subject but haven't seen one that addresses my situation.  Basically, I want to insert a new row with the number of columns to be inserted that depends on one of the parameters of the insert statement.  Here is some pseudo-SQL to illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
PARAMETERS
@CategoryID bigint,
@ChargeDate datetime2(7),
@Charge numeric(7,2),
@Mileage bigint,
@Gallons numeric(6,3),
@StartDate datetime2(7),
@EndDate datetime2(7)

IF @CategoryID = 1 THEN
    INSERT INTO VehicleExpenses VALUES(@CategoryID, @ChargeDate, @Charge, @Mileage, @Gallons)
ELSEIF @CatgegoryID = 2 THEN
    INSERT INTO VehicleExpenses VALUES(@CategoryID, @ChargeDate, @Charge)
ELSEIF @CatgegoryID = 3, 4 THEN
    INSERT INTO VehicleExpenses VALUES(@CategoryID, @ChargeDate, @Charge, @StartDate, @EndDate)
ELSEIF @CatgegoryID = 5 THEN
...and so forth
```

First, what is the correct SQL to accomplish this.  Second, maybe there is a better way to do this than with this SQL approach?  One idea I had was to use just one SQL statement and pass NULL values into the missing parameters but I cannot figure out how to pass a NULL value from a VB call to an SQL stored procedure.

Thanks in advace.

Comment: How many is the maximum amount of columns?

Comment: Always specify explicit field lists for insert statements, like `insert into vechicleexpenses (categoryid, chargedate, charge) values (@categoryid, @chargedate, @charge)`.

Comment: @RichBenner Max columns = 8

Comment: @Arvo Yes, I should have included the field lists but omitted them for the sake of simplicity of the pseudo-SQL

Answer (score 0):

> but I cannot figure out how to pass a NULL value from a VB call to an SQL stored procedure.

Pass [System.DBNull.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as the value of your parameter. If you still have problems show the rest of your VB. Your idea of using `null` values for the parameter values and having a single statement is indeed the best way to go as it will produce the least amount of variable code.

Comment: Yes, I thought using DBNull was the obvious route to go but I get a design time error using it.  For example, suppose p is one of the variables I want to send to the SQL Server.  I define p as 'Dim p As Nullable(Of Integer)' and then set it to null using 'p = DBNull.Value' gives a design time error of: Value of type 'DBNull' cannot be converted to 'Integer?'.  This is why I went to the SQL approach.